# android multipartentitybuilder not found post

Tags: android, multipartform-data

If add `reqEntity.addPart("file", fileBody);` it comes to android 5+ empty `reqEntity.addPart("user", user);` on android 4 works perfectly. Any help would be useful.

```
try{
            String TAG ="File UPL";
            // the file to be posted
            String textFile = _zipFile;
            Log.v(TAG, "textFile: " + textFile);
            // the URL where the file will be posted
            String postReceiverUrl = "http://my.com/file.php";
            Log.v(TAG, "postURL: " + postReceiverUrl);
            // new HttpClient
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            // post header
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(postReceiverUrl);


            File fle = new File(textFile);
            FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(fle);
            StringBody user = new StringBody(prefs.getString(PrefsName.USER_NAME, ""));
            StringBody pass = new StringBody(prefs.getString(PrefsName.USER_PASSWORD, ""));

            MultipartEntityBuilder reqEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
            reqEntity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            reqEntity.addPart("user", user);
            reqEntity.addPart("password", pass);
            reqEntity.addPart("file", fileBody);

            final HttpEntity yourEntity = reqEntity.build();

            class ProgressiveEntity implements HttpEntity {
                @Override
                public void consumeContent() throws IOException {
                    yourEntity.consumeContent();
                }
                @Override
                public InputStream getContent() throws IOException,
                        IllegalStateException {
                    return yourEntity.getContent();
                }
                @Override
                public Header getContentEncoding() {
                    return yourEntity.getContentEncoding();
                }
                @Override
                public long getContentLength() {
                    return yourEntity.getContentLength();
                }
                @Override
                public Header getContentType() {
                    return yourEntity.getContentType();
                }
                @Override
                public boolean isChunked() {
                    return yourEntity.isChunked();
                }
                @Override
                public boolean isRepeatable() {
                    return yourEntity.isRepeatable();
                }
                @Override
                public boolean isStreaming() {
                    return yourEntity.isStreaming();
                } // CONSIDER put a _real_ delegator into here!

                @Override
                public void writeTo(OutputStream outstream) throws IOException {

                    class ProxyOutputStream extends FilterOutputStream {
                        /**
                         * @author Stephen Colebourne
                         */

                        public ProxyOutputStream(OutputStream proxy) {
                            super(proxy);
                        }
                        public void write(int idx) throws IOException {
                            out.write(idx);
                        }
                        public void write(byte[] bts) throws IOException {
                            out.write(bts);
                        }
                        public void write(byte[] bts, int st, int end) throws IOException {
                            out.write(bts, st, end);
                        }
                        public void flush() throws IOException {
                            out.flush();
                        }
                        public void close() throws IOException {
                            out.close();
                        }
                    } // CONSIDER import this class (and risk more Jar File Hell)

                    class ProgressiveOutputStream extends ProxyOutputStream {
                        long totalSent;
                        File f = new File(_zipFile);
                        public ProgressiveOutputStream(OutputStream proxy) {
                            super(proxy);
                            totalSent = 0;
                        }
                        public void write(byte[] bts, int st, int end) throws IOException {
                            new_progres = true;
                            // FIXME  Put your progress bar stuff here!
                            totalSent += end;
                            publishProgress("" + (int) ((totalSent / (float) f.length()) * 100));
                            Log.e("up", st + "" + " - " + end);
                            out.write(bts, st, end);
                        }
                    }

                    yourEntity.writeTo(new ProgressiveOutputStream(outstream));
                }

            };
            ProgressiveEntity myEntity = new ProgressiveEntity();

            httpPost.setEntity(myEntity);
            // execute HTTP post request
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
            if (resEntity != null) {
                String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity).trim();
                Log.v(TAG, "Response: " +  responseStr);
                // you can add an if statement here and do other actions based on the response
                if (responseStr.equals("file_not_found")){
                    RESPONSE = responseStr;
                }else
                if (responseStr.equals("file uploaded succeeded")) {
                    RESPONSE = responseStr;
                }else
                if(responseStr.equals("file upload failed")) {
                    RESPONSE = responseStr;
                }
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: What seems to be the question? It's very unclear what you're asking

Comment: if i add file to reqEntity then in my php code $_POST == empty